# Laravel Backpack CRUDController return redirect() or skip middleware run redirect()

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

How can I run `return redirect()->to('/')` from the `protected function setupListOperation()` or any other method in CrudController.

As I check CrudController

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->crud = app()->make('crud');
            $this->crud->setRequest($request);

            $this->setupDefaults();
            $this->setup();
            $this->setupConfigurationForCurrentOperation();

//COMMENT: as I return from the setupListOperation, then it will run the below return $next.
            return $next($request);
        });
```

the `return $next($request);` will not execute my return redirect();

now my current solution is `die(redirect()->to('/'));`, but the down site is the page will show the text

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache, private Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 09:16:52 GMT Location: http://backpack.test/admin/ Redirecting to http://backpack.test/admin/.
```

how can I do it in a clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedro Martins @pxpm 21:24

@shiroamada if you want to redirect you have to overwrite the functions that should NOT be run by backpack, but should instead do your redirect. The ListOperation, is handled in index() method. So you need to overwrite the index() method of the ListOperation and do your redirects there. Here is how to overwrite the crud functions, change as needed: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-update#callbacks

```
    public function index()
    {
        //custom code for redirect
        if(!$this->crud->getCurrentEntryId())
        {
            $previous_url = parse_url(url()->previous());
            $member_id = ltrim($previous_url['query'], 'member_id=');

            return redirect('/admin/member/'.$member_id.'/show');
        }
        //.custom code for redirect
        
        //original index code
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('list');

        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['title'] = $this->crud->getTitle() ?? mb_ucfirst($this->crud->entity_name_plural);

        // load the view from /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/ if it exists, otherwise load the one in the package
        return view($this->crud->getListView(), $this->data);
    }
```